# Hide real ASP.NET page name

Tags: asp.net, url, html

can anyone tell me how i can hide the real name of a asp.net page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for URL rewrite

http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite

or

[Tip/Trick: Url Rewriting with ASP.NET](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Use URL Routing.If you are using asp.net 3.5/4.0 then it has inbuilt features.
check the following url for configuration of  URL Routing in asp.net 4.0

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/13/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Search in google for "URL Rewrite"